# increment float array ptr

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to move the float array ptr 256 "units" from the start so (256 * 4 bytes) for floats.
I am receiving a compile time error.

```
long new_capture_length = 4096;
long step_size = 256;
float data[new_capture_length];
data+=step_size;
```

error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘float[(long unsigned int)(new_capture_length)]’ and ‘float *’)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot "move" an array. You can move a *pointer into an array*, for example:

```
long new_capture_length = 4096;
long step_size = 256;
float data[new_capture_length];
float* p_data = &data[0];

p_data+=step_size; /* p_data now points 256 floats into data, i.e. to data[256]  */
```

But the location of `data` itself can never be altered, since it is not a pointer.

I gave a somewhat more detailed answer to a very similar question recently: [C Pointer Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613516/c-pointer-question/3613542) (I don't like to call "what's wrong with this code" type questions exact duplicates even if they have the same underlying problem).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memmove()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/) for moving data if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays can be used as pointers in some cases, but not all.  This is one where you can't.  You can't "move" an array like you can a pointer.   You have to either say `float* ptr = data + step size` (if all you want is a pointer) or use `memmove` to move the entire array.